# c# oracle проблема с кодировкой

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, oracle, запрос

При выполнении запроса, получаю вместо кириллицы знаки ????(перевернутые)
Как решить проблему?

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
...

//Коннект к БД        
public string oracledbConnect()
    {
        string Code = String.Empty;
        string conn = "DATA SOURCE="+ Ip +":"+ Port +"/" + ServiceName +";PASSWORD=" + Password +";PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID="+ Login;
        try
        { OraConn = new OracleConnection(conn); }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { return Code = ex.Message; }           

        return Code = "Success";
    }

//Выполнение запроса
public DataTable oraQuery(string query)
    {
        string resultQuery = String.Empty;
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        try
        {                
            OraConn.Open();

            OracleCommand oraComm = new OracleCommand(query, OraConn);                
            oraComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OracleDataReader reader = oraComm.ExecuteReader();                
            data.Load(reader);                    

            OraConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { string Error = ex.Message; }

        return data;
    }
```

UPD:nls_database_parameters

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET    WE8MSWIN1252
```

Comment: Затайте кодировку через sql-запрос  set -ом

Comment: @nick_n_a А пример можно ?  SELECT * FROM LIST_COUNTRY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в БД, неправильно была настроена.
Выяснилось при проверке, что ошибка в **nls_database_parameters** :

Как было:

```
NLS_LANGUAGE AMERICAN
NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8MSWIN1252
```

Как надо:

```
NLS_LANGUAGE RUSSIAN
NLS_CHARACTERSET  CL8MSWIN1251
```